# Code of this special table

Tags: tables

I am a new latex users and I can build only simple table
I must build a more complex table as depict in the follow image:
[image]

How can build this table code????

Comment: Go here and use this online table generator.  You will get the resulting code to paste into your project. http://www.tablesgenerator.com/#

Comment: You can try http://www.tablesgenerator.com/ to play and learn

Comment: This is actually quite easy with `multirow` and `\multicolumn{...}` and `\cline` commands. Or without `multirow` and manual placement of `layer` in the second row`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without any extra package and much ado, just using `\multicolumn` and `\cline` statements (and the usual tabular commands etc.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{tabular}{|l|*{8}{p{1.2cm}|}}
\hline
Derivative & \multicolumn{8}{c|}{Integral layer} \tabularnewline
\cline{2-9} 
layer & Type1 & Type2 &  Type3 &  Type4 &  Type5 &  Type6 &  Type7 &   Type8 \tabularnewline
\hline
A & & & & & & & & \tabularnewline
\hline
B & & & & & & & & \tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but what is \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}???

Comment: @LucaAngelino: It changes the vertical distance between lines in a table.

Comment: Of course, there are other setups, with `tabularx` and better spacing, but this 'minimal' setup works too;-)

Comment: @LucaAngelino: You're welcome. Happy TeXing!

Comment: What does the `*{8}` bit do?

Comment: @mrc: `*{8}{l}` does repeat the `l` specifier 8 times, which is easier than `llllllll`

Comment: I didn't know you could do that. Thanks!

Comment: @mrc: It's a feature which is not so wellknown, yes. You can use any of the specifiers, even the ones introduced with `\newcolumntype` (`array` package)

Answer (score 1):

Christian's answer gives the exact formatting, but here's one using [booktabs](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) that I think looks better:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % table is too wide for default margins
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum} % to show extent of margins

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{r *{8}{c}} \toprule
& \multicolumn{8}{c}{Integral layer} \\ \cmidrule{2-9}
Derivative layer & Type 1 & Type 2 & Type 3 & Type 4 & Type 5 & Type 6 & Type 7 & Type 8 \\ \midrule
A & & & & & & & \\
B & & & & & & & \\
C & & & & & & & \\
D & & & & & & & \\
E & & & & & & & \\
F & & & & & & & \\
G & & & & & & & \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{\label{tab:thetable} The table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```